# CSV import function adding a preceeding double quotation mark upon insertion in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, csv

so I've made this file which uploads a .csv file and then inserts the data in a mysql database, but, for some reason it adds an extra **"**(Quotation marks) at the start of data from the CSV file.
So for something :- **Laptop,Apple Mac,750,100,50** like this, it would insert in the database in the following way.

```
Category  Product Name Price1  Price2  Price3 
"Laptop     Apple Mac    750      100     50
```

I'm not sure why, but it adds a quotation marks before *Laptop*.

What can I do to fix this ?
Here's my code :-

```
<?php  
session_start();
include '../inc/inc.functions.php';
include '../dbconnector.php';
include '../dbpdo.php';
include '../inc/inc.config.php';
if((isset($_SESSION['admin'])) && ($_SESSION['admin'] == 1))
{
    $adminusername = $_SESSION['username'];
    $date=date('Y-m-d');
    if ($_FILES[csv][size] > 0) { 

        //get the csv file 
        $file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
        $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 
         //prepare the statement for the insertion of the record via PDO
        try{
            global $conn;

            $statement = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO products(category,productname,baseprice,basepricewd,basepricenw,addedby,addedon) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)");
            //loop through the csv file and insert into database 

            while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"))
            {
                if ($data[0]) { 
                    $statement->execute(array(
                        $data[0],
                        $data[1],
                        $data[2],
                        $data[3],
                        $data[4],
                        $adminusername,
                        $date));
                } 
            }
        // 
    }//try
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }


        //redirect 
       header('Location: admin_importproducts_home.php?success=1'); die; 
      //  echo "Products imported successfully";

    } 

 }
   else
{
    header('Location:http://domain.co.uk/' . $config["admindir"] . '/adminlogin');
}
?>
```

**CSV File**

```
Laptop,Apple Mac,750,100,50
```

CSV Image link :- https://i.stack.imgur.com/4v7Ez.png

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: thers not an extra " in the csv file?

Comment: Depends on your CSV.  You have used `'` as the text enclosure, maybe some are `"` or `"` is in the data?

Comment: Hi there.
No, there are no extra " in my csv file.

Comment: What do you see if you do `var_dump($data[0])`?

Comment: side note: LOAD DATA INFILE is hugely faster (as you not doing any other processing (currently))

Comment: @Barmar
I get string(7) ""Laptop"

Comment: I've never heard of `fgetcsv` adding a doublequote that wasn't in the original file, and I can't find anything like this in google. There has to be a quote before `Laptop` in the file.

Comment: clearly its in the file

Comment: @Barmar
I'm sure there are no quotation marks.
Image here :- http://i.imgur.com/WkpYeeU.png

Comment: lol thats excel! look at the file in a text editor. that's like looking a girl through the bottom of a beer glass, and saying shes hot :-)

Comment: Notice that Excel put all the columns in a single cell. It did that because there were quotes around the row, which prevented the commas from being treated as delimiters.

Comment: @Dagon

http://i.imgur.com/fSF73US.png

Comment: @Barmar
Sorry for the straight question, ho do I go about fixing it ?

Comment: there are quotes, but not in your notepad, so are you sure your looking at the file RAW and not copyingthat from excel ??

Comment: @Dagon
If I save the CSV as a .txt, I get this :- "Laptop,Macbook Pro,150,100,50"

Comment: You should probably fix the application that creates the file in the first place, so it doesn't write unnecessary quotes. If you're creating it in Excel, you should put each column in a different cell, not all in one cell. But if you can't fix the creator, use a text editor to remove the doublequotes at the beginning and end of each line.

Answer (score 0):

```
str_replace('"', '', $data[0] );
str_replace('"', '', $data[1] );
str_replace('"', '', $data[2] );
str_replace('"', '', $data[3] );
str_replace('"', '', $data[4] );

will solve the problem.
```